# Identify and replace block duplicates in a character vector

Tags: r

I have a string vector `a`.

```
a = c("Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Math","English","Math","Math","Physics","Physics","Chemistry")
```

Is there a quick and simple way to make it as follows?

```
c("Chemistry", NA, "Math","English","Math",NA,"Physics",NA,"Chemistry")
```

I have tried `diff` and `duplicated`, didn't get what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the adjacent elements of the `vector` to get a logical vector and assign those that are `TRUE` to `NA`.

```
a[c(FALSE,a[-1]==a[-length(a)])] <- NA
a
#[1] "Chemistry" NA          "Math"      "English"   "Math"      NA          "Physics"   NA          "Chemistry"
```

Or as the OP mentioned about `diff`, can convert to `factor`, coerce it to `numeric`, use `diff` and then assign to NA

```
a[c(FALSE,!diff(as.numeric(factor(a))))] <- NA
```

---

Or using `duplicated`

```
library(data.table)
a[duplicated(rleid(a))] <- NA
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach that uses `rle` and `replace`:

```
replace(a, sequence(rle(a)$lengths) > 1, NA)
# [1] "Chemistry" NA          "Math"      "English"   "Math"      NA         
# [7] "Physics"   NA          "Chemistry"
```