# Remove repeated numbers in a sequence

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a vector of the type

```
c(3,3,...,9,9,...,2,2,...,3,3,...,7,7,...)
```

I want to remove the repeated numbers in a sequence, without breaking the order. This is, I would like to obtain something like

```
c(3,9,2,3,7,...)
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323411/identify-and-replace-block-duplicates-in-a-character-vector), but again it is technically not a dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try with `rleid` and `duplicated`.  We create the run-length-ids with `rleid` (from `data.table`) so that only adjacent elements that are equal forms one group, get the logical index of not `duplicated` values and subset the vector.

```
library(data.table)
v1[!duplicated(rleid(v1))]
#[1] 3 9 2 3 7
```

---

Or as the OP mentioned, we can use `rle` from `base R` and extract the `values`.

```
rle(v1)$values
#[1] 3 9 2 3 7
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(3,3,9,9,2,2,3,3,7,7)
```

Answer (score 9):

We can also use the observation that a duplicate in sequence has a difference of 0 with their neighbour. Therefore, using base-R, we can do:

```
v[c(1,diff(v))!=0]
```

Comment: Note `rle(v)$values` handles `NA`s and non-numerical values "correctly". This solution works in the simplified case of numerical values without missing values only.

Comment: You are both right. However, missing data were not mentioned in the problem description, @Akrun's answer has been accepted and this answer has a warning in the comments. The upvotes are not my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, here is an `Rcpp` version of solving the problem:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericVector remove_multiples(NumericVector& vec) {   
   NumericVector c_vec(clone(vec));
   NumericVector::iterator it = std::unique(c_vec.begin(),c_vec.end());
   c_vec.erase(it,c_vec.end());
   return(c_vec);
  }'
)

x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,4,4,1,1)    
> remove_multiples(x)
[1] 1 2 1 3 4 1
```